# Is there a way to make a pivot table display data to specific individuals

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I have a pivot table with employee data I must share with them. As it stands they can see all other employees in the pivot table.

Is there a method for ensuring that employee A only sees their data, The only other option I can think about is making a separate worksheet for each employee but that's not ideal for the amount of employees

Comment: If the data for other employees really needs to be hidden then separate workbooks is the only solution.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Its a big workbook with several workbooks feeding into it. Is there no way to prompt the user to login with their employee number and auto filter the data to display only theirs and then lock the workbook

Comment: If you use VBA for that then the VBA can be altered by the user.  Instead of using (for example) the user's id, they could hard-code in any other user id.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -3):

To ensure employee A only sees their data, I can think of two options.

First, you could do an encryption of the pivot table.  This is a dynamic approach, where you must constantly update your system to modern cyber security standards.

Another option is you do not present the information to the user until it is obtained.  You can ensure that no one else can see someone else's data by utilizing a locking mechanism.  You can implement functionality for users to access the resource one at a time, where no two users can concurrently access the resource.

Comment: Thank you for the help, would you by any chance know where I could read up about this or find examples.

Comment: This answer doesn't really provide any actionable suggestions. How is the "encrypted" data decrypted for each user?  How is data "obtained" and/or "locked"?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).